# Uploaded App Show Default Icon on Google Play

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, apk

When I upload APK file on Google Store, It display Default App. I change icons @ all "drawable" folder. Its show my icon when I run program on emulator. I use Phonegap.

[image]

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.app.testeapp"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

        <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />




        <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|keyboard|locale" 
            android:name="com.app.testeapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap" 
                android:label="@string/app_name" 
                android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|keyboard|locale"> 
              <intent-filter></intent-filter> 
            </activity>

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: have you uploaded 512X512 size icon while deploying your app?

Comment: yes, in store listing. Right ?
High-res icon 
Default – English (United States) – en-US
512 x 512
32-bit PNG (with alpha)

Comment: did you fix it already?

Comment: @A.S. Yes, No method are useful for me, So I create a new Project With custom Icon and and Issue solved

Answer (score 1):

- HDPI-remove default icon
- MDPI-remove default icon
- XDPI-remove default icon

  The manifest app icon check.. if you have eclipse as a development check these icon under manifest one default icon may be there just delete it.

Comment: I am new in this line,
can you tell me how and where ?

Comment: do you know there are three folders for android diffrent resolution 
drawable-HDPI
drawable-MDPI
drawable-XDPI
MAY BE YOU HAV LEFT ONE ICON TO DELETE

Comment: In "res" folder right ?
drawable-hdpi,
drawable-ldpi,
drawable-mdpi,
drawable-xhdpi. First i remove all 4 icon and place my own there

Comment: YES EXACTLY...I CANT POST image so i cant show you
i had same problem. just chek there is a icon may be under manifest file if it is there delete that one also. hope it will work :)

Comment: the icon u hav for google play, what is the name of it /is it ic_launcer  if not remove it from manifest. Same case happened for me but chek in google play with diffrent resulution phone for which perticular device icon is coming diffrent (or simply remove all ic_launcher from the 3 difffrent folder if ur icon name is diffrent name from default one ).

Comment: where can I found google play icon,
Is it at another place. mean outside of drawable folder ?

Comment: no inside drawables chek the images which one is your googleplay icon
chek for three folder

Comment: no inside drawables chek the images which one is your googleplay icon
chek for three folder

Comment: In that folder every image name as "ic_launcher.png" Is I have to change it ?

Comment: what is the name of your app icon for googlr play

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38716/discussion-between-ali4android-and-shivam-pandya)

Answer (score 0):

Google Play shows the App Icon you have uploaded in their Backend. So please Upload the right one and it will be shown ;)